# Visual Workflow - Error message for Assignment Faults

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm currently using visual workflow, and I'm getting a fault on an assignment block. Is there any way to display what the fault message is, or can you only see fault messages on blocks with a fault output flow?

I need something like the fault output, but for the assignment block, since that is where it fails.

[image]

Comment: post a picture so that people can easily understand and response to your problem.

Comment: Added the picture

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no fault message for assignments.  More then likely there is some variable you're using which is null, ie hasn't been set.

The same thing will happen on a screen element.  What I do is create a Text message Variable, and put in all my Vars from the Assignment into the Text message.  Then place that on a debug screen.  When it fails I go back and start removing my vars from the Text Message until it works.  Then this tells me which var is causing my issue.